# MVC 6 with vNext: Do we still need the Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an application using MVC6.
I noticed that the `Global.asax` file disappeared by default there is `startup.cs` file that calls the config. My question is how do I grab the `Application_Start` event method ?

Do I still need the `Global.asax` ?
Why has it been removed by default ?

Comment: Global.asax is only present when there is a reason to hook into it.  The default MVC6 project has no hooks into it, therefore it doesn't provide one.  Just add new item, global.asax

Comment: Thank you! can you add this as answer so I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global.asax is only present when there is a reason to hook into it. The default MVC6 project has no hooks into it, therefore it doesn't provide one. Just add new item, global.asax

I should also suggest, that I would avoid creating a global.asax unless you need absolutely need it.  People tend to reach for Application_Start or Session_Start first when there are probably better places to do what you need to do.  Consider creating an OWIN module, or consider adding your own Startup module.

Comment: How would you replace Application_Error? if not using the global.asax?

Comment: @adinas - obviously there are still reasons to use it.. as I said, "unless you absolutely need it", and in the case of unhandled exceptions you do need it.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I was just wondering if they replaced global exception handling with something else.

Comment: @adinas - well, there are many ways to handle exceptions.. application_error is only one of them... HttpHandlers and modules are another, and depending on whether you're using mvc, webapi, webforms, etc.. there are also other options (like filters).  you just have to decide what works best for you.

Comment: there's a diagnostics package that you can use in your startup.