# Global Error Logging in ASP.Net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm testing out an MVC 6 Web Api and wanted to implement logging into a global error handler.  Just guaranteeing no errors get out of the system without being logged.  I created an ExceptionFilterAttribute and added it globally in the startup:

```
public class AppExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //Notice pulling from HttpContext Application Svcs -- don't like that
        var loggerFactory = (ILoggerFactory)context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof (ILoggerFactory));

        var logger = loggerFactory.Create("MyWeb.Web.Api");
        logger.WriteError(2, "Error Occurred", context.Exception);

        context.Result = new JsonResult(
            new
            {
                context.Exception.Message,
                context.Exception.StackTrace
            });
    }
}
```

Now in the startup, I'm adding this filter in:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AppExceptionFilterAttribute());
});
```

This all seems kind of brute force...is there a better way to get here using MVC 6?

Things I don't like or am unsure about with this approach:

1. Don't like pulling DI from http context
2. Don't have much context about the controller that originated the error (perhaps I can get it from the context in some way).

The other option I can think of is having a base controller that accepts an ILoggerFactory that all controllers inherit from.

Was wondering if there was some kind of diagnostics middleware that would allow logging to be inserted...

Comment: You can use the error event in global.asax. What dont you like about your existing approach?

Comment: @RyanDansie: In MVC 6 there is a move away from Global.asax, so I figured there was a better way to handle this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718640/mvc-6-with-vnext-do-we-still-need-the-global-asax

Comment: I also added some things I don't like in there...

Comment: The official docs have some tips: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You question has 2 parts. 1) DI injectable filters 2) Global error handling.

Regarding #1: You can use `ServiceFilterAttribute` for this purpose. 
Example:

```
//Modify your filter to be like this to get the logger factory DI injectable.
public class AppExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public AppExceptionFilterAttribute(ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
    {
       _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AppExceptionFilterAttribute>();
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

```
//Register your filter as a service (Note this filter need not be an attribute as such)
services.AddTransient<AppExceptionFilterAttribute>();
```

---

```
//On the controller/action where you want to apply this filter,
//decorate them like
[ServiceFilter(typeof(AppExceptionFilterAttribute))]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
....
}
```

You should be able to get the details of the controller from the `ExceptionContext` that is passed.

Regarding #2: From your previous post looks like you were playing with `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) & [extension source](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerExtensions.cs))...how about using that?...some info regarding it:

- This middleware is generic and is applicable to any middleware which
  is registered after it and so any concepts like controller/action
  info is specific to MVC which that middleware wouldn't be aware of.
- This middleware does not handle formatter write exceptions. You could
  write your own buffering middleware where you can modify the response
  body to be a buffered stream(MemoryStream) and let the MVC layer
  write the response to it. In the case of formatter write exceptions,
  you can catch it and send a 500 error response with details.

Comment: Thanks again @Kiran, I think the ErrorHandlerMiddleware is the solution I was looking for.  I actually didn't know that was out there.

Comment: I just ended up using the middleware linke above as a reference and created my own Middleware that logs the error only and then lets the exception bubble.  So just let the 500 error flow through and get the standard output.  I suppose if it's a 500 level error anyway, it's not something that can/should be easily parsed and retried.

Comment: What if I have a thread that runs outside owin? these exception handlers doesn't handle the exceptions raised inside that thread. I have read about an issue where it seemed to be a request about this but I'm not able to find the solution https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6398

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to perform global error handling is by using a `ILoggerProvider`.

The advantage to logging exceptions in this way is that **it also captures errors which occur in places that an attribute would not catch**. For example, exceptions that occur in Razor code could also be logged.

Here's a basic example with dependency injection:

### Provider

```
public sealed class UnhandledExceptionLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IMyErrorRepository errorRepo;

    public UnhandledExceptionLoggerProvider(IMyErrorRepository errorRepo)
    {
        // inject whatever you need
        this.errorRepo = errorRepo;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) =>
        new UnhandledExceptionLogger(errorRepo);

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

### Logger

```
public class UnhandledExceptionLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IMyErrorRepository errorRepo;

    public UnhandledExceptionLogger(IMyErrorRepository errorRepo)
    {
        this.errorRepo = errorRepo;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => 
        new NoOpDisposable();

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) =>
        logLevel == LogLevel.Critical || logLevel == LogLevel.Error;

    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            errorRepo.LogError(exception);
        }
    }

    private sealed class NoOpDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddTransient<IMyErrorRepository, MyErrorRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<UnhandledExceptionLoggerProvider>();
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    UnhandledExceptionLoggerProvider provider)
{
    loggerFactory.AddProvider(provider);

    // ... all the rest of your startup code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ASP.NET Core, but this solution should work.

I have a Middleware that I created to log all requests that go through the pipeline. In their, I just wrapped it in a try catch so if it throws an exception, it logs to my database.

```
       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var sessionId = GetSessionId(context);
            var path = context.Request.Path;

            var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            try
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
                watch.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                watch.Stop();

                await _errorRepo.SaveException(exception, context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(), sessionId);
            }
            finally
            {
#pragma warning disable 4014
                _requestLogRepo.LogRequest(
                    sessionId,
                    context.User.Identity.Name,
                    context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                    context.Request.Method,
                    path,
                    context.Request.ContentType,
                    context.Request.ContentLength,
                    startTime,
                    watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
#pragma warning restore 4014
            }
        }
```