# What is the best way to add an additional information to a log message with an exception in the ASP.NET-5 | MVC-6

Tags: c#, logging, error-handling, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to add some additional information to a log message with an exception from a controller.

A standard exception format is:

> TypeOfException. Message. StackTrace.

But it's not clear what is a source request of the exception. **When I receive an exception log to my email, I don't understand what is a request which led to the exception.** Therefore, I would like to add something like this for each exception from a controller:

> Request: GET: /api/something?param=1 User: currentUser TypeOfException. Message. StackTrace.

I tried to use the `AppExceptionFilterAttribute` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28968837/2631076):

```
public class AppExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.Exception = new Exception(
            RequestMessageBuilder.Build(context.HttpContext),
            context.Exception);
    }
}
```

It's working, but problem is that I have a duplicate of each message. The first exception log message don't has an additional information of a request, but the second has.

Why messages are duplicated?

**What is the best way to add an additional information to an exception from a controller?**

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Here is a configuration of my logger appenders:

```
        loggerFactory
            .AddConsole()
            .AddNLog(config =>
            {
                var mailTarget = new MailTarget
                {
                    Name = "Mail",
                    SmtpServer = Configuration["Email:SmtpClientHost"],
                    SmtpAuthentication = SmtpAuthenticationMode.Basic,
                    SmtpUserName = Configuration["Email:SmtpUserName"],
                    SmtpPassword = Configuration["Email:SmtpUserPassword"],
                    From = Configuration["Email:ServiceEmailAddress"],
                    To = Configuration["Email:DevelopersEmails"],
                    Layout = @"${time} ${level} ${message}",
                    Subject = "[${level}] " + Configuration["AppSettings:SiteTitle"],
                };

                config.AddTarget(mailTarget);
                config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Error, mailTarget));
            })
            .MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
```

Comment: How have you registered your `AppExceptionFilterAttribute`? Where do you log/send the email?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Yes, I have register the `AppExceptionFilterAttribute` in `ConfigureService`: `services.AddTransient<AppExceptionFilterAttribute>();` I log the email from a `NLog` appender.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I have updated my question and added a configuration of my logger. This information is useful?

Comment: Too many pieces I guess. In your filter attribute you just change the exception in the context, but where are logging that exception? I guess it would help if you can simplify the problem into something easier that reproduces the issue.