# Displaying a 404 Not Found Page for ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the middle-ware below to set up error pages for HTTP status codes 400 to 599. So visiting `/error/400` shows a 400 Bad Request error page.

```
application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
    {
        this.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        return this.View(statusCode);
    }
}
```

However, visiting `/this-page-does-not-exist` results in a generic IIS 404 Not Found error page.

Is there a way to handle requests that do not match any routes? How can I handle this type of request before IIS takes over? Ideally I would like to forward the request to `/error/404` so that my error controller can handle it.

In ASP.NET 4.6 MVC 5, we had to use the httpErrors section in the Web.config file to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/404/" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can use global.asax and `protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` to catch all errors, then redirect from there.  You'll need to check if it's an IsAjaxRequest but otherwise you can redirect based on the exception

Comment: This is ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 MVC 6. There is not Global.asax.

Comment: Really?  Are you sure?  Is that like you "*had* to use" httpErrors when you didn't *have* to?  There is no global.asax by default, just add one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718640/mvc-6-with-vnext-do-we-still-need-the-global-asax

Comment: I'm looking for a built in ASP.NET 5 method of doing this if there is one. ASP.NET 5 still requires a web.config file (to enable GZip compression etc.) so I'd rather use that than Global.asax.

Comment: found this related question but not sure it really answers the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421164/mvc-6-404-not-found

Comment: @JoeAudette Yes, that question is similar. Mine is specifically trying to get a custom 404 when navigating to ```/this-page-does-not-exist```. Too bad that question does not have an answer to this either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902135/asp-net-5-custom-error-page-does-not-render-on-azure-website), IIS gets the 404 (and therefore handles it) before it reaches `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute`.

Have you tried this: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/issues/144? It suggests terminating the request that received a 404 so it does not go to IIS to handle. And here's the code to add to your Startup to do so:

```
app.Run(context =>
{
   context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
   return Task.FromResult(0);
});
```

This appears to be an IIS-only issue.

Comment: This works but when I try to use ```application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");``` in conjunction with this code I get 404 errors all the time. Is there some way of combining the two?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadRehanSaeed, based on [this](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1501081), `App.Run()` is a catchall interface that fires when nothing else in the call chain handles a request. So if 404 is return for every request, there might be something else wrong with your `Startup.cs`. The code above should be at the end of your Startup.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed, the above code works on a test I did, with `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` using the same `ErrorController` you have. On my Startup, I have these in sequence: `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute()`, `app.UseMvc()`, the above `app.Run()` block, although changing the order of the first two does not matter. It returns the 404 custom error page only on non-existent resource.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have discovered that UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute  MUST come before UseMvc for it to work.

Comment: When I try this I get `Web server failed to listen on port xxxx`

Answer (score 29):

One of the best tutorials I found is this: https://joonasw.net/view/custom-error-pages

The summary is here:

1.
First add a controller like `ErrorController` then add this action to it:

```cs
[Route("404")]
public IActionResult PageNotFound()
{
    string originalPath = "unknown";
    if (HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey("originalPath"))
    {
        originalPath = HttpContext.Items["originalPath"] as string;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Note: You can add the action to another existing controller like `HomeController`.

2.
Now add the `PageNotFound.cshtml` view. Something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "404";
}

<h1>404 - Page not found</h1>

<p>Oops, better check that URL.</p>
```

3.
And the important part is here. Add this code to `Startup` class, inside `Configure` method:

```cs
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if(ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
        string originalPath = ctx.Request.Path.Value;
        ctx.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        ctx.Request.Path = "/error/404";
        await next();
    }
});
```

Note that it must be added before routing configs like `app.UseEndpoints...`.

Comment: Very important NOTE: must be added before routing configs like app.UseEndpoints

Comment: Another important thing missing from this answer, in the errorcontroller, add "[Route("error")]"

Comment: Also make sure you do not have an app.Use() before this.

Answer (score 10):

You can use fallback in EndPoint in asp.net core Like below (inside  app.UseEndpoints) and with razor pages (NotFound is a razor page in Pages folder instead controller)

```
 endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            
 endpoints.MapFallback( context => {
    context.Response.Redirect("/NotFound");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  });
```

Comment: `/NotFound` is not `Not Found`, but exists as a resource. If the resource indicated in the original request URI does not exist, the direct response should contain a 404 status and not found content, rather than a redirect.

Answer (score 3):

After working on few hours for handling 500 and 404 errors, I have implemented below given solution.

For handling `500` Server Side Errors you can use `app.UseExceptionHandler` middleware but `app.UseExceptionHandler` middleware only handles unhandled exceptions while `404` isn't an exception. For handling `404` errors I've designed another custom middleware which is checking response status code and if it is `404` then returning user to my custom `404` error page.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   else
   {
       //Hnadle unhandled exceptions 500 erros
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Pages500");
       //Handle 404 erros
       app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
       {
           await next();
           if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
           {
               //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
               ctx.Request.Path = "/Pages404";
               await next();
           }
       });
   }
```

**Note:** You must add `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Pages500");` middleware at the starting of your `Configure` method so that it can handle exceptions from all middlewares. The custom middleware can be placed any ware before `app.UseEndpoins` middleware but still, it's good to place in the beginning of `Configure` method.
`/Pages500` and `/Pages404` urls are my custom pages, you can design for your application.

Answer (score 2):

**Asp.net core 3.1 and 5**

in your `HomeController.cs` :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("/NotFound")]
   public IActionResult PageNotFound()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

in `Startup.cs` > `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.Use(async (context, next) =>
   {
      await next();
      if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
      {
         context.Request.Path = "/NotFound";
         await next();
      }
   });
   
   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```